# Scapy - How to sniff packet and send it as encapsulated data

Tags: python, scapy

I need to do the following:

- a) Use Scapy to sniff() on eth0. This will get me a scapy packet ..
  say X.
- b) Store X as a binary data into some variable... Y.
- c) Use zeromq IPC sockets to send off Y to another process.  I must use IPC,
  not tcp/udp.

Code:

```
def handler(x):
  x.show() #or do something .. 
  s = .. a zmq socket = ipc://myipcendpoint

  y = convert x to binary <== how to do this? 
  s.send(y) 


sniff(prn=handler, iface='eth0')
```

On the other process:

```
while 1: 
  y = s.recv()
  x = recover scapy packet from y
  ... do something with x ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str()` representation that Scapy implements should be enough for you.

```
y = str(x)
```

You can have Scapy parse it back into proper packet on the receiving end like so -

```
x = Ether(y)
```

From the [2nd code example in the Stacking-Layers](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#stacking-layers) section of the Scapy doc.